# Extract last part of a string in Lua

Tags: lua

I need to extract the last part of a string like this,

```
http://development.dest/show/images-345/name/289/
```

I only need this part `289`, I tried using `string.match` with the next pattern.

```
string.match(url, "(%d+)(\/)$")
```

And I get this error in error log,

```
2017/05/22 20:53:04 [error] 31264#0: *5 failed to load external Lua file
```

I think the last part of the pattern is wrong, but I don't know how to fix it (`(\/)`).

Comment: Instead of parentheses you need brackets, those create a character class, parentheses are for captures. Also, I added the question mark which matches 0 or 1 of the slashes as it may or may not be there. `"(%d+)[\/]?$"` is what you want. Is it possible to log or print out the result of the capture? That would make it easier to diagnose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message from Lua is

```
invalid escape sequence near '"(%d+)(\/'
```

which says that `\/` is not a valid escape sequence in Lua strings.

The simpler pattern below works just fine:

```
print(string.match(url, "(%d+)/$"))
```

If the final slash is optional, use

```
print(string.match(url, "(%d+)/?$"))
```

Comment: If the final slash would be optional, how pattern would be?

Answer (score 4):

Use [LuaSocket](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/home.html) to handle URLs.  This way you can also easily parse out the protocol, the query, etc without having to go through regex hell.

```
local url = assert(require"socket.url")

local parsed_url = url.parse"http://development.dest/show/images-345/name/289/"
local path       = url.parse_path(parsed_url.path)

print(path[#path])
```

Comment: Lua patterns are (not regex and) a delight to use!